# Trying to build a web scraper using python and running into difficulties where search parameters aren't defined in URL

Tags: python

so basically I'm attempting to build a data scraper that would pull all tariffs, alongside their yearly total from: https://www.energylinx.co.uk/energycalc.html?db=dual

The issue that I have is that on this website the search parameters aren't defined in the URL and therefore I am struggling to simply pull the data through requests.

I'm pretty new to python, but automating data scraping would assist greatly in my day to day.

Essentially, just looking on any assistance on how I'd go about automating this.

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing a get request to that url but you need to do a post request with the parameters required by that form e.g. need to pass the zip code, money amount ,etc

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.